# SQL - filtering the results of a union

Tags: sql, select, union

Have a union like this:

```
(SELECT prod.id, price, timestamp
FROM products prod JOIN prices price ON prod.id = price.productid
WHERE price > 0
GROUP BY prod.id, DATE(timestamp))
UNION
(SELECT prod.id, price, timestamp
FROM products prod JOIN prices price ON prod.id = price.productid
WHERE price = 0
GROUP BY prod.id, DATE(timestamp))
```

The problem:

If there are dates where a product is available with price = 0 and price > 0, we get two rows in the union result.

What we want is for the price = 0 result to be ignored if there is a price > 0 result for the same product on the same date.

Anyone who can share a trick for fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a "trick".   Just add a condition to the WHERE clause of the `price = 0` side of the UNION that filters out products that also have a price > 0.

I'd do it with a NOT EXISTS() function myself, but there are several other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to get the "have a price" to be grouped separately from the "only have a 0 price"?
if so then put the first group into a temp table do the select for the second group where the product ID isn't in the temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #HASPRICE (prod.id INT, price Decimal, timestamp DATE)

INSERT INTO #HASPRICE
SELECT prod.id, price, timestamp
FROM products prod JOIN prices price ON prod.id = price.productid
WHERE price > 0
GROUP BY prod.id, DATE(timestamp)

INSERT INTO #HASPRICE
SELECT prod.id, price, timestamp
FROM products prod JOIN prices price ON prod.id = price.productid
WHERE price = 0 AND prod.id not in (select prod.id from #HASPRICE)
GROUP BY prod.id, DATE(timestamp))
```

if not, then this will work

```
(SELECT prod.id, price, timestamp
FROM products prod JOIN prices price ON prod.id = price.productid
WHERE price >= 0
GROUP BY prod.id, DATE(timestamp))
```